# flutter's text with gradient color appears differently in ios and android

Tags: ios, flutter, gradient

my flutter app is showing text with gradient color. this is my code

```
final Shader linearGradientShader = ui.Gradient.linear(
  Offset(0, 20),
  Offset(150, 20),
  [Colors.red, Colors.yellow],
);
return Center(
  child: FittedBox(
    child: Text(
      '#stackoverflow',
      style: TextStyle(
        foreground: Paint()..shader = linearGradientShader,
        fontSize: 60,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

However in ios device, the text is not as smooth as android. how can i fix this? image below is ios

[image: android]
[image: ios]

Comment: Are these "on device".  The resolution of the simulators and emulators can be deceiving.

Comment: yes, both images are on device images

Answer (score 0):

Text rendering vary between Android and IOS, to improve this you can try setting the font size and antialiasing settings :

```
final dpr = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
```

> MediaQuery.devicePixelRatio is a property that tells you the ratio of
> physical pixels to logical pixels on a device’s screen.

```
Text('#stackoverflow'),
style:TextStyle(
foreground:Paint()..shader=linearGradientShader,
fontSize:60*dpr,
fontWeighty:FontWeight.bold,
textAntialias:true,),),
```

Try this hope this helped!

You can read about MediaQuery.devicePixelRatio from here to have a clear idea about it :
[https://flutterassets.com/most-popular-flutter-mediaquery-properties/#:~:text=devicePixelRatio%20in%20Flutter%3F-,MediaQuery.,of%20the%20device's%20pixel%20density.](https://flutterassets.com/most-popular-flutter-mediaquery-properties/#:%7E:text=devicePixelRatio%20in%20Flutter%3F-,MediaQuery.,of%20the%20device%27s%20pixel%20density.)

Comment: this helped, but still is not as clear as android's. Plus, I can't find textAntialias field in TextStyle. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Try using custom fonts , also try the package : super_text_layout 0.1.7  [link](https://pub.dev/packages/super_text_layout)